# Cascading Dropdownlist is not working with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to do one dropdownlist and one listbox. When I select a value in dropdownlist, the listbox has to change. I'm trying to do this with Jquery, because I'm using MVC. But when I select the ID in the first dropdownlist, nothing happens. My code:

View (Jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IDCONCESSAO').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Localidades/LocalidadesMunicipio',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { ConcessaoId: $(this).val() },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        options += '<option value="' + this.IdLocalidade + '">' + this.NomeLocalidades + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#IDLOCALIDADE').prop('disabled', false).html(options);
                }
            });
        });
    });

            </script>
```

Dropdownlist and listbox part:

```
     <%:   Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SINCO_CONCESSAO,  new SelectList(ViewBag.IDCONCESSAO, "Id", "Nome"), new { @class = "select", style = "width: 250px;" }) %>
    </div>
       <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
       Localidades:
    </div>
      <div class="editor-field" id="Localidades">
       <%: Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItemIds, Model.ItemChoices, new { id = "IDLOCALIDADE", size = "10" })%>
 </div>
```

The action that do the cascade:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LocalidadesMunicipio(int ConcessaoID)
    {
        var Localidades = (from s in db.LOCALIDADES_VIEW
                           join c in db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ToList() on s.ID_MUNICIPIO                          equals c.IDMUNICIPIO
                      where c.IDCONCESSAO == ConcessaoID
                      select new
                      {
                          idLocalidade = s.ID_LOCALIDADE,
                          NomeLocalidades = s.NOME_LOCALIDADE
                      }).ToArray();

        return Json(Localidades);
    }
```

Controller:

```
       [Authorize(Roles = "ADMINISTRADOR")]
    public ActionResult Create(SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO model)
    {
 //Here I populate my dropdownlist
        ViewBag.IDCONCESSAO = from p in db.SINCO_CONCESSAO.ToList()
                              join c in db.MUNICIPIOS_VIEW.ToList() on p.IDMUNICIPIO equals c.ID_MUNICIPIO
                              join d in db.SINCO_TIPO_CONCESSAO.ToList() on p.IDTIPOCONCESSAO equals d.IDTIPOCONCESSAO
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = p.IDCONCESSAO,
                                  Nome = p.IDCONCESSAO + " - " + c.NOME_MUNICIPIO + " - " + d.DSTIPOCONCESSAO
                              };

 //Here I populate my listbox           
        PopulateItemLocalidades(model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

I can't see what is wrong T_T
What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first drop down most likely has an ID of `SINCO_CONCESSAO`, by the name of the property it was created for. And you are referring to something different in your script.

To fix this, either specify a different ID in jQuery:

```
$('#SINCO_CONCESSAO').ajax ...
```

or set an ID for a dropdown in View:

```
 <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SINCO_CONCESSAO,  ...
     , new { id = "IDCONCESSAO" ... }) %>
```

Comment: Additionally, if your JS is in the view, and you're using MVC 4 + a better practice may be $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SINCO_CONCESSAO)").ajax...

Comment: @rashleighp, can you please give a link to this `Html.IdForm`? I am not able to find this method in msdn

Comment: Sorry, it's "IdFor" - typo. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Basically it returns a string that is the id tag that is automatically generated by MVC for form input/select/textarea etc.

Comment: @rashleighp, cool, did not see it before. But I *suspect* this is created for something like `<label for=""` kind of thing, and it might not be a good idea to pollute javascript with such. Thanks for sharing though.